# add_index :name, :email:, unique: true not working for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I seen this question before on here but the solution on there is not working for me. [Rake Aborted , on add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765223/rake-aborted-on-add-indexusers-email-unique-true) 
In the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl he wants you to add_index :name, :email, unique: true I keep getting this error message.

> $ bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
== 20141224060705 AddIndexToUsers: migrating ==================================
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: indexed columns are not unique: CREATE UNIQUE INDE
X "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")c:/Sites/example/db/migrate/2014122
4060705_add_index_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

there are no users in the database. here is a picture of the database

Comment: I can't add the image I don't have a reputation on here

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose the attributes you want to add the index into an array like so:

```
add_index :users, [:name, :email], unique: true
```

The first argument is the table name, the second can be an array of attributes or a single attribute, and then some options.

Hope this helps!