# Ruby on Rails DB Migration issue - Column not unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm following the https://www.railstutorial.org/book/ guide to understand a bit more about it. I'm stuck at 6.3.3, where it tells to create a secure password. The previous migration seemed to have worked (to create a unique index and to create the secure password column). After that when i try to run:

```
rake test
```

it says that the test was aborted and that i should run:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

but when i do run the command above it returns this:

```
c:\Sites\sample_app>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
== 20141226095217 AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating =============================
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true}) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: indexed columns are not unique: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")c:/Si tes/sample_app/db/migrate/20141226095217_add_index_to_users_email.rb:3:in `change' C:in `migrate' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't understand why this is happening. My DB is empty.

As requested, the migrations files:

20141226095217_add_index_to_users_email.rb

```
class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

20141226095746_add_password_digest_to_users.rb

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: please show us `db/migrate/20141226095217_add_index_to_users_email.rb` and previos migration file too.

Comment: Errors say that you already have index on email. Remove `unique: true` from `AddIndexToUsersEmail` migration.

Comment: thanks @Зелёный, your suggestion worked, but it is strange since I haven't define uniqueness before that. Well, thanks anyway =)

Comment: just check actual `db/scheme.rb` for your database schema before run generate migration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rake Aborted , on add\_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765223/rake-aborted-on-add-indexusers-email-unique-true)

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14765346/429758 for the exact same issue. As mentioned there, the issue is not with the migration, but with having duplicate values for `email` field in the users table.

Since this error is happening while running tests, it means the test database has duplicate emails for users.

Rails Tutorial book uses fixtures to setup test data. The `test/fixtures/users.yml` file used to create the users on test env is shown in [Listing 6.29](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#code-default_fixtures) as follows:

```
one:
  name: MyString
  email: MyString

two:
  name: MyString
  email: MyString
```

Both of these fixtures having `MyString` as email is what is causing the migration to fail. Change the values to make sure both have different values.

Example:

```
one:
  name: First User
  email: first@example.com

two:
  name: Second User
  email: second@example.com
```

### EDIT

Looking back at the Rails Tutorial, the next step in [Listing 6.30](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#code-empty_fixtures) is to empty the `test/fixtures/users.yml` file. That is another way to ensure this error does not occur.